# Как создать нейронную сеть для определения геолокации

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

В определенное время с определенной точки был сделан заказ еды. У меня есть следующие данные

- Геолокация - откуда заказали еду.
- Дата заказа
- День недели заказа
- Погода в день заказа

Цель создания нейронной сети в том чтобы натренировать эту нейронную сеть, после чего предсказывать заказы. Например - в каких местах завтра больше всего будут заказывать.

Какой тип нейронной сети необходимо использовать для решения этой задачи?
Какой фреймворк или библиотеку для нейронных сетей лучше использовать для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Мне ответили на этот вопрос в англоязычном сообществе. Кого интересует - читайте [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406209/how-to-create-a-neural-network-for-finding-geolocation/43406414#43406414)

Answer (score 0):

Для предсказания наверно лучше использовать рекуррентные сети(rnn, lstm). Ну а в качестве фреймворка выбирайте то что подходит под ваши требования(ОС, язык программирования, документация и прочее). Я бы посоветовал Keras/tensorflow